# ReactJS: beginner task - adding a line break

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a chat in ReactJS (for practice). I just started playing around with it but I'm not sure if my approach is correct. I managed to add text on input on the main chat div, but I am not sure about how to add a br after each message in the main chat div. Currently it just concatenates text.

```
    class Chat extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {

            super(props);

            this.state = {
                text: props.text,
                message: ''
            }

            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);

        }

        handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({message: event.target.value});
        }

        sendMessage(event) {

            event.target.value = ''

            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                text: this.state.text + this.state.message, // I tried here to add a br but with no success
                message: ''
            }));

            event.preventDefault();

        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.text}
                    </div>

                    <form onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>

                </div>
                );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Chat text='' />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: Not what you are asking, but I think it would be better to push messages to an array and map that to a list/paragraphs. This way you wouldn't need manual linebreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try instead of having a single string representing all messages, have an array of elements (probably div's) with one for each message. The default display of div's will give you a break between each message. Then you can style it your self to add more spacing or whatever you want.

See here:

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            messages: [],
            message: ''
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({message: event.target.value});
    }

    sendMessage(event) {
        let messages = this.state.messages;
        messages.push(
            <div key={this.state.messages.count + 1}>
                {this.state.message}
            </div>
        );

        this.setState({
            messages: messages, 
            message: '',
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.state.messages}
                </div>

                <form onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Chat />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `'\n'` between the two variables or you can use template literals.

> With template literals, any new line characters, tabs, spaces, etc. inserted in the source become a part of the string.

But you should use `pre` element to wrap the string because it preserves the line break otherwise react simply renders the string.

```
sendMessage(event) {
   event.target.value = ''
   this.setState((state, props) => ({
      text: this.state.text + '\n' + this.state.message ,
      // using template literals
      // text: `${this.state.text}
// ${this.state.message}` ,
      message: ''
   }));
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

And in render method

```
<div>
   <pre>{this.state.text}</pre>
</div>
```